# From the debs Gazebo wants to remove ros-hydro-desktop-full

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi folks.

The Gazebo ROS integration tutorial suggest to install `ros-hydro-desktop-full`. OK. And then, to install `gazebo`. But this last package suggest to remove the previous one.

Do we have to keep `gazebo-prerelease`?

Thx.

```
arnaud@hercules:~$ sudo apt-get install gazebo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ffmpeg fltk1.3-doc fluid freeglut3-dev gir1.2-gtk-2.0 libasound2-dev
  libatk1.0-dev libav-tools libavahi-client-dev libavahi-common-dev
  libavcodec-dev libavdevice53 libavfilter2 libavformat-dev libavutil-dev
  libbullet libbullet-dev libcaca-dev libcairo-script-interpreter2
  libcairo2-dev libcf0 libdbus-1-dev libflann-dev libflann1.7 libfltk-forms1.3
  libfltk-images1.3 libfltk1.1 libfltk1.1-dev libfltk1.3 libfontconfig1-dev
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgl2ps-dev libglib2.0-dev libgtk2.0-dev
  libharfbuzz-dev libhdf5-7 libjasper-dev libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore
  libnetcdf-dev libnetcdfc++4 libnetcdfc7 libnetcdff5 libogg-dev
  libpango1.0-dev libphonon4 libpixman-1-dev libpulse-dev libpyside-dev
  libpyside-py3-1.1 libpyside1.1 libqhull-dev libqwt-dev libqwt5-qt4 libqwt6
  libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl1.2-dev libshiboken-dev
  libshiboken-py3-1.1 libshiboken1.1 libslang2-dev libswscale-dev
  libtheora-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev libv4l-dev libvtk5-dev libvtk5.8 libwebp4
  libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev
  libxft-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxml2-dev libxml2-utils libxrandr-dev
  libxrender-dev libxss-dev libyaml-cpp-dev libyaml-cpp0.3 phonon
  phonon-backend-gstreamer python-epydoc python-jinja2 python-kitchen
  python-matplotlib python-matplotlib-data python-opengl python-pydot
  python-pyparsing python-pyside python-pyside.phonon python-pyside.qtcore
  python-pyside.qtdeclarative python-pyside.qtgui python-pyside.qthelp
  python-pyside.qtnetwork python-pyside.qtopengl python-pyside.qtscript
  python-pyside.qtsql python-pyside.qtsvg python-pyside.qttest
  python-pyside.qtuitools python-pyside.qtwebkit python-pyside.qtxml
  python-qt4-dev python-qwt5-qt4 python-sphinx python-tz ros-hydro-actionlib
  ros-hydro-actionlib-msgs ros-hydro-actionlib-tutorials ros-hydro-amcl
  ros-hydro-angles ros-hydro-base-local-planner ros-hydro-bfl
  ros-hydro-bond-core ros-hydro-bondpy ros-hydro-camera-calibration
  ros-hydro-camera-calibration-parsers ros-hydro-camera-info-manager
  ros-hydro-carrot-planner ros-hydro-clear-costmap-recovery
  ros-hydro-collada-parser ros-hydro-collada-urdf ros-hydro-common-msgs
  ros-hydro-common-tutorials ros-hydro-compressed-depth-image-transport
  ros-hydro-compressed-image-transport ros-hydro-convex-decomposition
  ros-hydro-costmap-2d ros-hydro-cv-bridge ros-hydro-depth-image-proc
  ros-hydro-diagnostic-aggregator ros-hydro-diagnostic-analysis
  ros-hydro-diagnostic-common-diagnostics ros-hydro-diagnostic-msgs
  ros-hydro-diagnostic-updater ros-hydro-diagnostics ros-hydro-driver-base
  ros-hydro-driver-common ros-hydro-dwa-local-planner
  ros-hydro-eigen-conversions ros-hydro-eigen-stl-containers
  ros-hydro-executive-smach ros-hydro-fake-localization ros-hydro-filters
  ros-hydro-gazebo-msgs ros-hydro-gencpp ros-hydro-genlisp
  ros-hydro-geometric-shapes ros-hydro-geometry
  ros-hydro-geometry-experimental ros-hydro-geometry-msgs
  ros-hydro-geometry-tutorials ros-hydro-gmapping ros-hydro-image-common
  ros-hydro-image-geometry ros-hydro-image-pipeline ros-hydro-image-proc
  ros-hydro-image-rotate ros-hydro-image-transport
  ros-hydro-image-transport-plugins ros-hydro-image-view
  ros-hydro-interactive-marker-tutorials ros-hydro-interactive-markers
  ros-hydro-ivcon ros-hydro-joint-state-publisher ros-hydro-kdl-conversions
  ros-hydro-kdl-parser ros-hydro-laser-assembler ros-hydro-laser-filters
  ros-hydro-laser-geometry ros-hydro-laser-pipeline ros-hydro-librviz-tutorial
  ros-hydro-map-msgs ros-hydro-map-server ros-hydro-message-filters
  ros-hydro-message-generation ros-hydro-mk ros-hydro-move-base
  ros-hydro-move-base-msgs ros-hydro-move-slow-and-clear ros-hydro-nav-core
  ros-hydro-nav-msgs ros-hydro-navfn ros-hydro-navigation
  ros-hydro-nodelet-core ros-hydro-nodelet-topic-tools
  ros-hydro-nodelet-tutorial-math ros-hydro-octomap ros-hydro-opencv2
  ros-hydro-openslam-gmapping ros-hydro-orocos-kdl ros-hydro-pcl
  ros-hydro-pcl-conversions ros-hydro-pcl-msgs ros-hydro-pcl-ros
  ros-hydro-perception-pcl ros-hydro-pluginlib-tutorials
  ros-hydro-polled-camera ros-hydro-python-qt-binding ros-hydro-qt-dotgraph
  ros-hydro-qt-gui ros-hydro-qt-gui-app ros-hydro-qt-gui-core
  ros-hydro-qt-gui-cpp ros-hydro-qt-gui-py-common ros-hydro-random-numbers
  ros-hydro-resource-retriever ros-hydro-robot-model ros-hydro-robot-pose-ekf
  ros-hydro-robot-state-publisher ros-hydro-ros ros-hydro-ros-comm
  ros-hydro-ros-tutorials ros-hydro-rosbash ros-hydro-rosboost-cfg
  ros-hydro-rosbuild ros-hydro-rosclean ros-hydro-rosconsole-bridge
  ros-hydro-roscpp-tutorials ros-hydro-roscreate ros-hydro-rosdoc-lite
  ros-hydro-roslang ros-hydro-roslaunch ros-hydro-roslisp ros-hydro-rosmake
  ros-hydro-rosmaster ros-hydro-rosnode ros-hydro-rosout ros-hydro-rosparam
  ros-hydro-rospy-tutorials ros-hydro-rostest ros-hydro-rostopic
  ros-hydro-rosunit ros-hydro-roswtf ros-hydro-rotate-recovery
  ros-hydro-rqt-action ros-hydro-rqt-bag ros-hydro-rqt-bag-plugins
  ros-hydro-rqt-common-plugins ros-hydro-rqt-console ros-hydro-rqt-dep
  ros-hydro-rqt-graph ros-hydro-rqt-gui ros-hydro-rqt-gui-cpp
  ros-hydro-rqt-gui-py ros-hydro-rqt-image-view ros-hydro-rqt-launch
  ros-hydro-rqt-logger-level ros-hydro-rqt-moveit ros-hydro-rqt-msg
  ros-hydro-rqt-nav-view ros-hydro-rqt-plot ros-hydro-rqt-pose-view
  ros-hydro-rqt-publisher ros-hydro-rqt-py-common ros-hydro-rqt-py-console
  ros-hydro-rqt-reconfigure ros-hydro-rqt-robot-dashboard
  ros-hydro-rqt-robot-monitor ros-hydro-rqt-robot-plugins
  ros-hydro-rqt-robot-steering ros-hydro-rqt-runtime-monitor
  ros-hydro-rqt-rviz ros-hydro-rqt-service-caller ros-hydro-rqt-shell
  ros-hydro-rqt-srv ros-hydro-rqt-tf-tree ros-hydro-rqt-top
  ros-hydro-rqt-topic ros-hydro-rqt-web ros-hydro-rviz
  ros-hydro-rviz-plugin-tutorials ros-hydro-rviz-python-tutorial
  ros-hydro-self-test ros-hydro-sensor-msgs ros-hydro-shape-msgs
  ros-hydro-shape-tools ros-hydro-smach ros-hydro-smach-msgs
  ros-hydro-smach-ros ros-hydro-stage ros-hydro-std-srvs
  ros-hydro-stereo-image-proc ros-hydro-stereo-msgs ros-hydro-tf
  ros-hydro-tf-conversions ros-hydro-tf2 ros-hydro-tf2-bullet
  ros-hydro-tf2-geometry-msgs ros-hydro-tf2-kdl ros-hydro-tf2-msgs
  ros-hydro-tf2-py ros-hydro-tf2-ros ros-hydro-tf2-tools
  ros-hydro-theora-image-transport ros-hydro-timestamp-tools
  ros-hydro-trajectory-msgs ros-hydro-turtle-actionlib ros-hydro-turtle-tf
  ros-hydro-turtlesim ros-hydro-urdf ros-hydro-urdf-parser-plugin
  ros-hydro-urdf-tutorial ros-hydro-urdfdom ros-hydro-urdfdom-headers
  ros-hydro-vision-opencv ros-hydro-visualization-marker-tutorials
  ros-hydro-visualization-msgs ros-hydro-visualization-tutorials
  ros-hydro-voxel-grid ros-hydro-xacro shiboken sphinx-common sphinx-doc
  tango-icon-theme tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev x11proto-composite-dev
  x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-render-dev x11proto-scrnsaver-dev
  x11proto-xinerama-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gazebo-prerelease ros-hydro-desktop-full ros-hydro-gazebo-plugins
  ros-hydro-gazebo-ros ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-pkgs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gazebo
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/37,4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 13,8 MB disk space will be freed.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4048/from-the-debs-gazebo-wants-to-remove-ros-hydro-desktop-full/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 316 on 2013-08-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2013-08-02**:
I guess the package ros-hydro-desktop-full package allready installed the Gazebo Version you are looking for! (The other Version is probably 1.86 or so without the new Ros-Integration...)

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on 2013-08-02**:
Thx for the comment. I would have said `gazebo` is the 1.9.0 and the `1.9.5` ... according to my tries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There is a temporary lag in the release system, as soon as the next update to Hydro is released ros-hydro-desktop-full will pull gazebo, not gazebo-prerelease

---

Originally posted by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) with karma: 369 on 2013-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/21/tfoote/) on 2013-08-02**:
The repository was just synced.  The new versions of ROS Hydro packages are built against the gazebo package no longer the gazebo-prerelease package.

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on 2013-08-04**:
Thx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can remove `gazebo-prelease`.

Hydro does not automatically install gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-08-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-08-02**:
i believe once the next public ROS update is released, hydro-desktop-full will install Gazebo automatically